# adding multiple classnames using classname package based on jason state

Tags: reactjs

I have a json with different timing and I want to change the classname based on this timing state.

```
{
"jobs": [ 
  {     
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Web Designer/Developer",
      "location": "Tehran",
      "time": "full time",
      "company": "/images/l1.png"
  },
  {     
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Marketing Director",
      "location": "Tehran",
      "time": "part time",
      "company": "/images/l2.png"
  },
  { 
      "id": 3,
      "title": "C Developer(senior)",
      "location": "Tehran",
      "time": "freelance",
      "company": "/images/l3.png"
  },]}
```

I tried classnames package but I think something is wrong because it doesn't work:
Note that it is a functional react componennt

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
const className = classNames({
    'btn text-tiny self-center' : true,
    'border-lightgreen text-lightgreen' : job.time === 'full time',
    'border-lightpurpel text-lightpurpel' : job.time === 'part time',
    'border-red text-red' : job.time === 'freelance'
})

<button className={className}>{job.time.toUpperCase()}</button>
```

Comment: The only difference to documentation I can see is, you are using multiple classes in one entry/as property name. Not sure this is working.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?
Edit: Works fine in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-breeze-0ilc2

Comment: nothing happens just they wont be added to my text!

Comment: Would you like to use some other package?

Comment: If yes then you can use `clsx` - https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-multiple-classnames-9gfxi

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with react functional's `useState`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const json = {
  jobs: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Web Designer/Developer",
      location: "Tehran",
      time: "full time",
      company: "/images/l1.png"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Marketing Director",
      location: "Tehran",
      time: "part time",
      company: "/images/l2.png"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "C Developer(senior)",
      location: "Tehran",
      time: "freelance",
      company: "/images/l3.png"
    }
  ]
};

const CustomButton = ({ jobIndex }) => {
  const job = json.jobs[jobIndex];
  const initialValue =
    job.time === "full time"
      ? "border-lightgreen text-lightgreen"
      : job.time === "part time"
      ? "border-lightpurpel text-lightpurpel"
      : job.time === "freelance"
      ? "border-red text-red"
      : "btn text-tiny self-center";
  const [className, setClassName] = useState(initialValue);
  return <button className={className}>{job.time.toUpperCase()}</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  return <CustomButton jobIndex={0} />;
}
```

[image: Edit SO-classnames-module (forked)]